# Tensorflow in Android: java.lang.illegalArgumentsException

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

I want to put a tensorflow model on Anroid.
I recently noticed that the results of running the same data in Python and Android, respectively, are inconsistent.
After several trial and error, I found that the input data I entered when I ran the model on Android was wrong.
It was just a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` error, and I think I put the data correctly, but I have no idea what went wrong.

I used images that were transformed into image resizing and gray scale as learning data. in Python
I did the same preprocessing on Android.
My image type is `.jpg`

I attached my source.

Source related to image preprocessing

```
btntrans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                image_bitmap = resizeBitmapImage(image_bitmap, 28);
                image_bitmap = RGB2GRAY(image_bitmap);
                image.setImageBitmap(image_bitmap);

                byte[] byteArrayRes = bitmapToByteArray(image_bitmap);
                float[] inputArray = bytetofloat(byteArrayRes);
                activityPrediction(inputArray);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    });
```

Everything happens when I click the button

resizeBitmapImage method

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmapImage(Bitmap source, int maxResolution)
{
   int width = source.getWidth();
   int height = source.getHeight();
   int newWidth = width;
   int newHeight = height;
   float rate = 0.0f;

   if(width > height)
   {
       if(maxResolution < width)
       {
           rate = maxResolution / (float) width;
           newHeight = (int) (height * rate);
           newWidth = maxResolution;
       }
   }
   else
   {
       if(maxResolution < height)
       {
           rate = maxResolution / (float) height;
           newWidth = (int) (width * rate);
           newHeight = maxResolution;
       }
   }

   return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, newWidth, newHeight, true);
}
```

RGB2GRAY method

```
public Bitmap RGB2GRAY(Bitmap image){
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmOut;
    bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(int y = 0 ; y < height; y++){
            int pixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
            int A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            int R = Color.red(pixel);
            int G = Color.green(pixel);
            int B = Color.blue(pixel);
            R = G = B = (int)(0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B);
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));

        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}
```

bitmap to byte array method

```
private byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

bytetofloat method

```
public float[] bytetofloat(byte[] array){
    int[] returnArr = new int[array.length/4];
    float[] returnArr1 = new float[array.length/4];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < returnArr.length; i++){
        //array[i] = 0;
        returnArr[i] = array[i*4] & 0xFF;
        if(returnArr[i] < 0 || returnArr[i]>255)
            Log.d("ARRAY", returnArr[i]+" ");
        returnArr1[i] = (float)returnArr[i];
    }
    return returnArr1;
}
```

When I run it with the above source, I get this error exactly.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: buffer with 308 elements is not
>   compatible with a Tensor with shape [1, 28, 28]

28 * 28 is Input image size
Before image resizing, it had an average width of 20 and a height of 36.
The strange thing is that the number 308 is changed to 306, 307 and fixed.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method for converting Java **BufferedImage** to **Tensor** object:

```
    private static Tensor<?> convertImageToArray(BufferedImage bf) {
    int width = bf.getWidth();
    int height = bf.getHeight();
    float[][][][] rgbArray = new float[1][height][width][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            bf.getRaster().getPixel(i, j, rgbArray[0][i][j]);
        }
    }
    return Tensor.create(rgbArray);
}
```

Your problem is probably in missed channels of your image. Float array length must be equal to

```
height * width * channels
```

of the image.